# No recipient addresses found in header - Sendmail

Tags: scripting, perl, email, csh

From C shell script I am invoking a perl script to send an email,

```
/path/send/email/email.pl "abc@gmail.com" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Perl script

```
print "To: ".$ARGV[0]."\n";
```

But I am getting an error

```
unable to read file
No recipient addresses found in header
```

Kindly help.

Comment: You've two commands here so split the problem into two parts. First of all, is the output of `/path/send/email/email.pl "abc@gmail.com"` a valid email message?

Comment: Yes it is a valid email message. Kindly suggest on how I can solve this issue.

Comment: It can't have been - as shown in an answer you weren't including the abc@gmail.com on the "To" line. Please recheck: are you producing a valid email message?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this can't be resolved by us, as the primary error is [coming from the custom script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623019/no-recipient-addresses-found-in-header-sendmail?noredirect=1#comment1165649_623047)

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by valid email message?

Comment: There are two issues here. First of all, your own custom script is generating the "unable to read file" message - you said as much in an [earlier comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623019/no-recipient-addresses-found-in-header-sendmail?noredirect=1#comment1165649_623047). We cannot help you with this because you haven't shared it (and quite reasonably, probably don't want to). Secondly, at least your "To:" line of your email message has been [demonstrated as incorrect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/623047/100397), so `sendmail` cannot parse it

Answer (score 1):

Perl arrays by default start at index 0.

Use print print `$ARGV[0]` instead of `$ARGV[1]`.

**Additionally**

1. add `-i` option to sendmail command line to disable special treatment of lines starting with dot (`.`).
2. Add empty line after email headers.

Comment: Also, you might want to mention that interpolating the variable, i.e. `print "To: $ARGV[0]\n"`, is more idiomatic (less like typical PHP)

Comment: I did try the above suggested however the issue remains the same. I have another argument passed for ARGV[0] so I am passing my email address in the second argument. So that should not be a prob, apart from that i tried with -i in the sendmail like this /usr/sbin/sendmail/ -i -t  and didn't work. Also added a empty line after email headers.

Comment: Run "naked" perl script (`/path/send/email/email.pl "abc@gmail.com"` without pipe to sendmail) and inspect email message it generates.

Comment: I did run the script without the pipe to sendmail and it gives a msg                                              Unable to read file.

Comment: Then THERE is your problem  Fix your script